# Publishing multiple apps under same package - Android

Tags: android, packaging

I have an application that supports different domains. My code is developed under the package: com.example. I would like to publish multiple application under different packages like:

> com.example.domain1, com.example.domain2, etc.

In the manifest I define:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.domain1"
```

....
and for domain2:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.domain2"
```

The problem I am facing is that once I change the base package name from domain1 to domain2 I need to rename all my packages in the src folder as well as layouts. What I am looking for is to keep the same base packaging com.example and distribute the different apps under its sub-domains.

Is there a better way?

Clarification:
When changing the package name, the resources file changes from com.example.R to com.example.domain2.R. This means that I have to go into all src java classes and layouts etc. and update the generated R file location. That is not handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up marking my main project as a library and then creating a project for each domain and linking to the library.

No need to play around with the manifest or the R.java file.

Thanks to @Tenfour04 for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: can you be more specific how you did it ?

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, each Activity, Service, Provider and Receiver has a `name` attribute. By default they use a shortcut like `".MainActivity"` The leading `.` is a shortcut for the `package` name at the top level of the manifest.

So if you don't want to rename all those packages in the src folder, just type out explicit names for the Activities, Services, Providers, and Receivers in your manifest, for example, `android:name="com.example.sharedmultiprojectdomainname.MainActivity"`.

Comment: Yes, that solves the Manifest file. But my src packages are still com.example and not com.example.domain1 which I think is required per Android spec.

Comment: I don't think that's true. Is Google Play not letting you upload them?

Comment: If you use any libraries, those are full of all kinds of source packages, and I've never had any problems with that. If you use the Facebook SDK, you have to add the com.facebook.LoginActivity to your manifest, and that works fine.

Comment: Using this method is actually even worse since then I have to go and update all the Activites (and other classes) as I change between the domain apps.

Comment: No, with this method, the only line of code you have to change between projects is the `package` line in the manifest. Unless I misunderstand what you're trying to do.

Comment: The solution you suggest solves the "fixing" of names of activities etc. But I still have the problem of the R.java file changing the package it is generated in. I have found out that passing --custom-package to the aapt can set the package to be com.example. But I am not sure how to set that in eclipse.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I had forgotten about the resources. Try making your main project a library project (Properties->Android), then make a second project and put your launcher icons and strings (app name string) resources in the second project and have the second project reference the first library. I don't think the second project needs any classes in it as long as its manifest is using full path names for the activities, services, etc. If this works, then you only need to modify the `package` in the manifest of the second project to change between builds.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gradle as your build system, you might want to incorporate build variants into your build, which will solve package problems. More on this can be found in this [Google I/O speech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCJAgPkpmR0#t=1150)

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry but I do not use Gradle. In any case, before going to a build solution, I need to know how to solve manually :-)

Comment: I understand. But Gradle support it out of the box, so you don't have to do it manually. It is already done for you.